# Refreshing fragment listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a activity (Activity A) with a fragment that has a ListView inside of it and I'm calling another activity (Activity B) to add records to the fragment's list.

My problem is that calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` on Activity A's onResume/onFragmentResume and the fragment's onResume changes nothing.

My adapter is populated in Activity A's onCreate.

I also tried inserting the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in a runOnUiThread.

Any one tackled this situation before?

Comment: Both seem to be tackled, I only suspect you're not adding data to the proper collection. Can you show us how you're setting the adapter and how you're populating data?

Comment: Ugh... I totally forgot that I was working with a SQLite DB and forgot to refresh the DB data in Activity A. It's fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good suggestion but try to reinitialize the adapter and set it again and tell me if it is work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your adapter in the fragment in either the onAttach(), or onViewCreated() methods.  You could also populate it in the onCreate() of the fragment, then call notifyDataSetChanged in either of these lifecycle methods I suggest.

These methods will be called whenever the fragment is connected and drawn, thus, you can be sure that it will populate your Fragment correctly.

In general, have all your view related items (like adapter creation and population) in your fragment, and navigation (ActionBar, and flowing between Activities) in your Activity.